# Calling an Action from an Action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gree

I am creating a game in `Unity3d` using the GREE `c#` API.
I am trying to get run an `Action` for every (username, score) in a leader board.

The code is the following:

```
public static void LoadBestScoreFromFriends(Action<FriendAndScore> onComplete)
{
    Gree.Leaderboard.LoadScores(LEADERBOARD_ID,
        UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.UserScope.FriendsOnly,
        UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.TimeScope.AllTime,
        1,
        100,
        (IScore[] scores) => {

        foreach (IScore iscore in scores)
        {
            // Since the username is needed, a second
            // call to the API must be done
            Gree.User.LoadUser(iscore.userID, 
            (Gree.User guser) => {
                FriendAndScore friend = new FriendAndScore();
                friend.Name = guser.nickname;
                friend.Score = "" + iscore.value;

                // Run the action for every (nickname, score value)
                onComplete(friend);
            }, (string error) => {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't fetch friend! error: " + error);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem here is that the `iscore.value` it's always the same. It's the last element of the `foreach`. This make sense because the `LoadUser()` finishes after the `foreach` ends its loop.

I thought of creating a second method to do the call there. Something like:

```
private void GetTheUserAndCallTheAction(Action<FriendAndScore> onComplete, string userID, string score)
{
    Gree.User.LoadUser(userID, 
            (Gree.User guser) => {
                FriendAndScore friend = new FriendAndScore();
                friend.Name = guser.nickname;
                friend.Score = score;
                onComplete(friend);
            }, (string error) => {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't fetch friend! error: " + error);
            });
}
```

Since I am a `C#` newbie I wanted to know if there is a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design - this is how capture works when constructing lambda expression in foreach loop and executing this lambda later.

Fix - declare local copy of `IScore iscore`:

```
foreach (IScore eachScore in scores)
{
   IScore iscore = eachScore;
```

And [Closing over the loop variable...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) by Eric Lippert details the behavior and related issues.